# PyCharm code completion: how to prevent space key and "dot" from committing lookup item

Tags: pycharm

How does one disable the space key from committing the suggestion when using code completion?

If I attempt to name something "req" for example, when I'm done typing, and enter a "space," I wind up with "request" instead -- this being just one example.

I don't see it anywhere in the keymap, and have seen this mentioned in other places without any apparent solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's a 'Preselect the first suggestion' option in **IDE Settings | Editor | Code completion** section. What is it set to? Try to use 'Smart' and 'Never' options to see which one works better for you.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that setting to begin with, as I'm so used to Visual Studio; that's why this became an issue to begin with. I have it on "smart" now, with a modified keymap.  I don't see anywhere that lets you adjust which keys commit the lookup item...oh well.